# AWS API Gateway with Custom Authorizer and CORS Intermittent 200 then 403 then 200 ... Strange

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have an 1 Amazon Api Gateway setup with a custom authorizer (the authorizer basically just returns allow for anything)

I enabled CORS, and this is running from **jQuery** webpage.

I have two method

1. /vehicles (returns a list of car)
2. /bookings (returns booking details)

The behavior I am seeing, is the first request goes fine, I see it pull the **OPTIONS**, then perform a **GET** request. **Then**, I hit the other method the **OPTIONS** works, then the get returns a **403**, but if I launch the request again (*On the same resource*), I get a **200**

I'm using Cloudformation, but I noticed the same behaviour when I was using the Serverless Framework.

Below are some screen shots for my sanity and hopefully someone else has seen this strangeness.

[image]

[image]

Below is a portion of my Cloudformation YAML template, I'm learning this as I do it.

```
 HelloAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Environment}
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        securityDefinitions:
          test-authorizer:
            type: apiKey
            name: Authorization
            in: header
            x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
            x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
              type: token
              authorizerUri:
                Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AuthorizerFunc.Arn}/invocations
              authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 5
        paths:
          /vehicles:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${VehiclesLambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
              security:
                - test-authorizer: []
            options:
              tags:
              - "CORS"
              summary: "CORS support"
              description: "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n"
              consumes:
              - "application/json"
              produces:
              - "application/json"
              parameters: []
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: "Default response for CORS method"
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                      type: "string"
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                      type: "string"
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: "string"
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: "mock"
                requestTemplates:
                  application/json: "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: "200"
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    responseTemplates:
                      application/json: "{}\n"
          /bookings:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${BookingsLambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
              security:
                - test-authorizer: []
            options:
              tags:
              - "CORS"
              summary: "CORS support"
              description: "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n"
              consumes:
              - "application/json"
              produces:
              - "application/json"
              parameters: []
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: "Default response for CORS method"
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                      type: "string"
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                      type: "string"
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: "string"
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: "mock"
                requestTemplates:
                  application/json: "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: "200"
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                    responseTemplates:
                      application/json: "{}\n"
```

This is my **Anything Goes Authorizer**:

```
'use strict';

const generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    const authResponse = {};
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        const policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17';
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        const statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke';
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }
    return authResponse;
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log("Hit Authorizer")
    console.log(event)


    callback(null, generatePolicy('user123', 'Allow', event.methodArn));

};
```

Anyone else seen this, or know how to debug it ?

I put this on a test site, just it some one wants to see what I am seeing.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflowisgreat2/index.html

Comment: can you post content of authorizer?

Comment: Added the Authorizer

Comment: make sure your statementOne.Resource = resource has this format "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/". In your case to allow all that would be "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/*/"

Comment: Dung, I'm not sure exactly where you are suggesting to put that.. In the API Definition in the YAML ? or in the Authorizer.

Comment: In your authorizer, at the line "statementOne.Resource = resource;"

Comment: That Worked !  I changed it to arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:761861444952:z3msgut90g/*/*/* and I'm good to go.. Can you explain what was going on, and I'll give you credit for answering this. Thank you so much

Comment: Moved my answer to answer section for easier explain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the custom authorizer code, at the line

```
statementOne.Resource = resource;
```

change your resources to this format "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/".

In your case to allow all that would be:

```
statementOne.Resource = arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/*/
```

This is how AWS understands your authorizer. Because in custom authorizer you can get information from the request header like user, group, etc and then validate the info against your authorization database and decide who or what is allowed to continue the request type POST/GET/OPTION, but API gateway won't know your decision until you provide it with a valid answer in AWS format

```
{
  "principalId": "yyyyyyyy", // The principal user identification associated with the token sent by the client.
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow|Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:{regionId}:{accountId}:{appId}/{stage}/{httpVerb}/[{resource}/[child-resources]]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "stringKey": "value",
    "numberKey": "1",
    "booleanKey": "true"
  },
  "usageIdentifierKey": "{api-key}"  # Optional
}
```

You can visit this page to understand more about it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html

Answer (score 0):

Just talked with an AWS rep about a similar issue. The issue at hand is lambda authorizer caching, which is different than API Gateway caching.

You likely have your lambda authorizer caching by default (see photo), so when you initially make a request, your policy (which is specific to a singular resource), gets cached for the TTL. Subsequent requests to DIFFERENT RESOURCES which use the SAME LAMBDA AUTHORIZER will return the SAME POLICY for your original resource, which is not the resource at hand, and as a result, you get a 403.

Changing the returned policy to something more general a la @Dominic Nguyen's answer is one solution (usually involves adding /*s), but you can also do what I did and just disable caching on your lambda Authorizer:

[image: lambda authorizer cache settings]
Then, REMEMBER to REDEPLOY!!! Rep told me to wait 30 seconds after that, then test.

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that API Gateway will used a cached authorizer response for a different resource, that just doesn't make any sense!

Comment: From what I've seen, by default the authorizer result's cache key is the resourcePath, and after a fair amount of testing I'm confident in asserting that the key is sensitive to parameter values in the path (eg. `/user/{userId}`). If you include an authorization header in the identity sources, you can be confident that nobody's going to receive a cached response for a different resource / or someone else's request to the same resource.

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity above, please refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78140892/2860309) for clarification: `/user/{userId}` in this case would be matched literally, so the cached authorizer response would be for a different path! In this case where the identity sources don't include some kind of key/token in the request headers, using a wildcard resource has potentially catastrophic security implications.

Answer (score 0):

I found all the answers so far quite confusing, so I ran some tests and have come to the conclusion that the way authorizer caching works is counterintuitive and potentially dangerous to naive users (as it is, the documentation is extremely opaque).

Let's say I've configured a Lambda authorizer using the default identity source - the context's `resourcePath` - and the resource path includes a parameter, then the cache key will only have a single entry for all the matching resources, eg. `/user/{userId}` will cache the returned policy for the first user requested.

In the above case, if the cached policy's `resource` attribute is set to the precise ARN for `user/123`, then every other request to the resource will hit the cached policy and be rejected because the policy is explicitly applied only to `user/123`. If the policy matches on a wildcard, as suggested in other answers, then *every other user requested will have that cached policy applied*, which could have catastrophic implications depending on the application.

If there's no cache entry yet and I make two requests simultaneously to the same `resourcePath` - eg. I request both `user/123` and `user/456` - then the authorizer will be run for both of them and it's anyone's guess which result will be cached. Perhaps both? Either way, any subsequent requests for the same resource path will used the cached policy, and the request will be authorized based on whether the new request's path matches the cached policy's `resource` attribute.

I'm guessing it's standard practice to include an Authorization header in the identity sources, in which case the cache would only be hit when it's the same user making the request, but in my case I'm retrieving an identifier from a path parameter and so caching on the resource path leads to very unexpected results. I've now set my identity source to be the context `path` instead, with the policy being returned matching the exact same path, and things seem to be working as desired.